# Javascript Help Needed: Replace href value substring with another substring

Tags: javascript, html, replace

What I am looking to do is use Tamper/Grease-monkey JS script to change HREF value substring X and replace with substring Y. Not sure if this should happen after the page loads (maybe before?). Jquery is not an option for me. Using class ID for href, as seen in example HREF below is not an option (I cannot implement IDs either). This should work in FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE11.

EXAMPLE:

Target HREF: `<a href="http://herp.derp.com/apps/dumpcr?&amp;content=summary&amp;format=html&amp;identifier=1234567890" title="1234567890" target="_blank">1234567890</a>`

Replace THIS X: `"herp.derp.com/apps/dumpcr?&amp;content=summary&amp;format=html&amp;identifier="`

With THAT Y: `"meow.now.com/app/quicker_meow/?bug="`

This is what I am working with now but when I hover over the hyperlinks in the doc, nothing has changed.

```
onload=function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('herp.derp.com/apps/dumpcr?&amp;content=summary&amp;format=html&amp;identifier=','meow.now.com/app/quicker_meow/?bug=');
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your work for you. Show what you tried, include your code as a [mcve]

Comment: If I knew the correct approach yet it was failing then I would post code. As stated, but you removed from my original post, "I am very new to JS". If you are not willing to help or this is not the place where a newbie would go then that is fine. But you did change the context of my request for assistance by nullfying my first statement ("I am VERY new to JS"). If you feel like it's not worth your trouble then maybe someone else won't mind making a suggestion. I am not requesting for someone to code the full solution. My research on this site has not yielded the outcome I desire. Thanks.

Comment: I just followed the editing culture on this site - [Read this post for reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296391/should-phrases-such-as-i-am-new-to-x-be-edited-out-of-questions) (_Such content is noise; feel free to remove it when editing such posts._) You are more than wolcome to [edit] your post, but with relevant details

Comment: I edited your post (again), but this time I just improved the formatting of the code. Hope you find a solution, and don't take my edits personally :) Good luck

Comment: Don't do `document.body.innerHTML = ...`. That will cause the entire HTML to be re-parsed, and all Javascript references to DOM elements will be invalidated.

Comment: OK. Thanks Alon. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the links first and then replace substrings in their hrefs.

Try this and put in in your `onload`:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){
  links[l].href =  links[l].href.replace("trololo", "foobar")
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/trololo">link 1</a>

<a href="https://www.example.com/test/trololo=666">link 2</a>
```